# How to read a binary file into an array of bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have a binary file which I am reading to a collection of byte arrays.

The file contains multiple (arbitrary number) of records.  Essentially a block of bytes.  Each record is of arbitrary length.

The header of the file provides the offsets of each of the records.

```
record 0: offset 2892
record 1: offset 4849
....
record 98: offset 328932
record 99: offset 338498
```

I have written code to do loop and read in each record to it's byte array.  Looking at difference in offsets gives me the record size.  A seek to the offset and then a call to ReadBytes() reads the record into its array.

My current incomplete solution won't work for the last record.  How would you read that last record into an array (remember it is of arbitrary length).

As for why?  Each record is encrypted and needs to be decrypted separately.  I am writing code which will read in each record into a byte array.  Decrypt it and then write all the record back to a file.

Code added at request:

```
    //recordOffsets contain byte location of each record start.  All headers (other than universal header) are contained within record 0.
    recordBlocks = new List<RecordBlock>();

    //store all recordOffsets.  Record0 offset will be used to load rest of headers.  Remaining are used to parse text of eBook.
    for (int i = 0; i < standardHeader.numRecs; i++)
    {
        RecordBlock r = new RecordBlock();
        r.offset = bookReader.ReadInt32(EndianReader.Endian.BigEndian);
        r.number = bookReader.ReadInt32(EndianReader.Endian.BigEndian);
        recordBlocks.Add(r);
    }

    foreach (RecordBlock r in recordBlocks)
    {
        if (r.number  == recordBlocks.Count)
        {
            ///deal with last record
        }
        else
        {
            r.size = recordBlocks[(r.number) + 1].offset - r.offset;   
        }
        bookReader.Seek(r.offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        r.data = bookReader.ReadBytes(r.size);            
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Length property from the FileInfo Class to determine the total number of bytes, so that you can calculate the amount of bytes of the last record as well.
So you can keep most of your current logic.

Comment: I will attempt that.  If not I will try Aamir "break it up" method.  I was just hoping there was something like a ReadToEnd method which would output a byte array.

Comment: Bingo.  Was actually easy to implement once you got me thinking about it.  I just added a pair of lines inside the if block above. I likely will refactor it later to clean up the code (get & store file size earlier).  

FileInfo f = new FileInfo(inFile);

r.size = (int)f.Length - r.offset;

Answer (score 6):

`System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()` will read all bytes in Byte Array and after that you can read from that byte array record by record.

Comment: Yeah I was considering that.  I would read into one "master array" and then use a sequence of copies to break it into records.

Answer (score 1):

your problem which seems to me is **how will you get the actual record size of the last record.**

Either you may add this information in the header explicitly then your code will work as charm in my thoughts.

Comment: I have no control over the layout of the file, I guess that isn't clear from the question.  Trust me there are a lot of things I would change with the file if I could.

Comment: :) , huh problem then , let me think something else

Comment: Aamir solution seems fesiable , i think you should try that one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a .net guy, but it would seem you have a couple options.  There's got to be a way to tell the size of the file.  if you can find that, you can read everything.  alternatively, the msdn description for binaryreader.readbytes() says thT if you ask for mroe than the stream contains you'll get whatever's in the file.  do you know the max size of the blob you're reading?  if so, just read that into pre-cleared memory.